# Glorified classes in the Java language

Tags: java

Some classes in the standard Java API are treated slightly different from other classes. I'm talking about those classes that couldn't be implemented without special support from the compiler and/or JVM.

The ones I come up with right away are:

- `Object` (obviously) as it, among other things doesn't have a super class.
- `String` as the language has special support for the + operator.
- `Thread` since it has this magical start() method despite the fact that there is no bytecode instruction that "forks" the execution.

I suppose all classes like these are in one way or another mentioned in the JLS. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Anyway, what other such classes exist? Is there any complete list of "glorified classes" in the Java language?

Comment: [Generics](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html) almost fit, but not quite.  They're implemented using a compiler trick, but they're not isolated to one class.

Comment: They are all reverence types. ;-)

Comment: Is "thread.start" magical? Surely it's just some native code called to do this?

Comment: That thought has struck me too. Perhaps the JNI alone is sufficient to implement the Thread class. I suppose if I would try to do this, I would use some OS-level thread api, fork the execution in the implementation of the start() method, execute the run() method in the forked thread, and return. But then *my* OS thread would keep running. Would that run smoothly along with the threads created by the JVM? and honor the JLS memory model and so on?

Comment: According to the spec, the only way to create a thread is from the Thread class (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Threads.doc.html#22488). Of course, it relies on some naitive level communication with the JVM, but if you did your own JNI, you might start a thread, but you wouldn't get the JVM to understand what you are doing (locks, memory model, etc.). Thread is privileged in that the spec assigns it a special privilege - the sole way to start a thread.

Answer (score 35):

There are a lot of different answers, so I thought it would be useful to collect them all (and add some):

### Classes

- **AutoBoxing** classes - the compiler only allows for specific classes
- **Class** - has its own literals (int.class for instance). I would also add its generic typing without creating new instances.
- **String** - with it's overloaded +-operator and the support of literals
- **Enum** - the only class that can be used in a switch statement (soon a privilege to be given to String as well). It does other things as well (automatic static method creation, serialization handling, etc.), but those could theoretically be accomplished with code - it is just a lot of boilerplate, and some of the constraints could not be enforced in subclasses (e.g. the special subclassing rules) but what you could never accomplish without the priviledged status of an enum is include it in a switch statement.
- **Object** - the root of all objects (and I would add its clone and finalize methods are not something you could implement)
- **References**: WeakReference, SoftReference, PhantomReference
- **Thread** - the language doesn't give you a specific instruction to start a thread, rather it magically applies it to the start() method.
- **Throwable** - the root of all classes that can work with throw, throws and catch, as well as the compiler understanding of Exception vs. RuntimeException and Error.
- **NullPointerException** and other exceptions such as ArrayIndexOutOfBounds which can be thrown by other bytecode instructions than athrow.

### Interfaces

- **Iterable** - the only interface that can be used in an enhanced for loop

---

#### Honorable mentions goes to:

- java.lang.reflect.**Array** - creating a new array as defined by a Class object would not be possible.
- **Annotations** They are a special language feature that behaves like an interface at runtime. You certainly couldn't define another Annotation interface, just like you can't define a replacement for Object. However, you could implement all of their functionality and just have another way to retrieve them (and a whole bunch of boilerplate) rather than reflection. In fact, there were many XML based and javadoc tag based implementations before annotations were introduced.
- **ClassLoader** - it certainly has a privileged relationship with the JVM as there is no language way to load a class, although there is a bytecode way, so it is like Array in that way. It also has the special privilege of being called back by the JVM, although that is an implementation detail.
- **Serializable** - you could implement the functionality via reflection, but it has its own privileged keyword and you would spend a lot of time getting intimate with the SecurityManager in some scenarios.

Note: I left out of the list things that provide JNI (such as IO) because you could always implement your own JNI call if you were so inclined. However, native calls that interact with the JVM in privileged ways are different.

Arrays are debatable - they inherit Object, have an understood hierarchy (Object[] is a supertype of String[]), but they are a language feature, not a defined class on its own.

Comment: @Donal, very true, I was thinking of runtime annotation, but source level annotations were indeed done that way (xdoclet most notibly, or even in core java with @deprecated)

Comment: I've just been fighting my way through a thicket of code that was originally written with xdoclet processing and then converted to annotations. Oh, how I prefer annotations to that (even though, with suitable maven incantations, the net effect is the same).

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585, Collections are a standard api that could be built by anyone in a different way (in fact there are alternative implementations that are geared around primitives, as well as a very famous Google project which enhances them). The only thing they get which is special is Iterable, which is mentioned in the answer. They are the bread and butter of java programming, to be sure, but they are just regular classes, with no special privileges.

Comment: @Yishai While developing any application, the major thing that takes importance is DATA MANAGEMENT. We all can do a task in different number of ways, but the optimized way is the one which occupies less memory and which has less usage of unnecessary references. By using Collections we can sort,search,and compare large amount of data, which provides predefined algorithms like Binary Search,Merge Sort etc. It also provides us Comparator and Comparable Interfaces to customize our techniques.  Collections class may not be the best class in java,but it is undoubtedly a class of glorified qualities.

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585, I think you misunderstand the thrust of the question. It isn't about what classes are important (I agree with your statement about the importance of Collections), rather which ones are priviledged by the JVM or language spec in a way that you could not accomplish with KK_SuperDuperCollections, for example.

Comment: @Yishai hmmmm ... which means Collections is important but it is not a  (unique) class can be developed only by JVM. Is it what you want to sa y ?

Comment: @KK_07k11A0585, yes, exactly.

Comment: What about `SecurityManager`? Or anything related to reflection or serialization?

Comment: @Antimony, I'm not actually sure. Off hand I don't know of anything special there, but maybe there is.

Answer (score 19):

`Class`, of course. It has its own literals (a distinction it shares with `String`, BTW) and is the starting point of all that reflection magic.

Comment: Ah, good point. So what's an example of a class literal? Are you referring to MyClass.class?

Comment: @aioobe: exactly. Note that you also have int.class, char.class, etc.

Answer (score 13):

[sun.misc.unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) is the mother of all dirty, spirit-of-the-language-breaking hacks.

Answer (score 12):

1. Enum.  You're not allowed to subclass it, but the compiler can.
2. Many things under java.util.concurrent can be implemented without JVM support, but they would be a lot less efficient.

Comment: You can anonymously subclass enums (which is the base of the visitor pattern impl. for enums values). But yes, you cannot fully subclass an enum ;-)

Answer (score 11):

All of the [Number classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) have a little bit of magic in the form of [Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Comment: You mean the classes that wrap primitives - which also includes Boolean and Character; but excludes BigInteger.

Comment: @emory: Right, just the primitive wrapper classes.  Unfortunately that does exclude BigInteger.

Answer (score 10):

Since the important *classes* were mentioned, I'll mention some interfaces:

The `Iterable` interface (since 1.5) - it allows an object to participate in a foreach loop:

```
Iterable<Foo> iterable = ...;
for (Foo foo : iterable) {

}
```

---

The [`Serializable`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface has a very special meaning, different from a standard interface. You can define methods that will be taken into account even though they are not defined in the interface (like `readResolve()`). The `transient` keyword is the language element that affects the behaviour of `Serializable` implementors.

Comment: True, They are interfaces though, so they require no "special" implementation per see. (Similar to Throwable.)

Comment: Serializable actually does require special implementation. It's an interface that you're expected to have two methods (I forget the names... I could google it...) but they aren't required or defined in the standard interface scheme.

Comment: @glowcoder: however, once could argue that all the specialness of Serializable is not relevant to the Java language, only to the implementation of ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt it has - the `transient` keyword

Comment: Since you mention Iterable, can we consider Comparable also in that interfaces list?

Comment: I don't think so - `Comparable` doesn't take part in anything internal. You could easily write `NewComparable` and new `NewArrays.sort(..)` with the same functionality

Comment: I agree with @Bozho - it's not integrated (although it is widespread and useful!)

Comment: @glowcoder: Actually, everything you need is exposed. You just have to turn off access controls via `AccessibleObject.setAccessible()`.

Comment: which might throw a security exception ;)

Answer (score 6):

1. **Throwable**, RuntimeException, Error
   AssertionError
2. **References** WeakReference, SoftReference, PhantomReference
3. Enum
4. Annotation

Comment: Nice list. +1, Annotation is an interface though, and has no implementation.

Comment: Annotations are treated differently by the compiler than normal interfaces. Similar to enum they all extend Annotation, and the compiler does that automagically. From the JavaDoc of Annotation: The common interface extended by all annotation types. Note that an interface that manually extends this one does not define an annotation type. Also note that this interface does not itself define an annotation type. So you can't create an annotation using normal syntax, they needed to change the compiler to add them.

Answer (score 6):

Java array as in `int[].class`

Comment: Ah, good one! the `[I` class ;) it's not an API class though.

Answer (score 4):

[`java.lang.ClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), though the actual dirty work is done by some unmentioned subclass (see [12.2.1 The Loading Process](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.2.1)).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this. But I cannot think of a way to manually implement IO objects.

Comment: You're right, they can't be implemented in pure Java. They need to be implemented through JNI (just as any other class that needs to do system calls). Apart from that however, they need no special support from compiler or jvm.

Answer (score 2):

There is some magic in the `System` class.

`System.arraycopy` is a hook into native code

```
public static native void arraycopy(Object array1, int start1, 
  Object array2, int start2, int length);
```

but...

```
/**
 * Private version of the arraycopy method used by the jit
 * for reference arraycopies
 */
private static void arraycopy(Object[] A1, int offset1,
  Object[] A2, int offset2, int length) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Heys what do you mean by your second part of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well since the special handling of assert has been mentioned. Here are some more Exception types which have special treatment by the jvm:

- NullPointerException
- ArithmeticException.
- StackOverflowException
- All kinds of OutOfMemoryErrors
- ...

The exceptions are not special, but the jvm uses them in special cases, so you can't implement them yourself without writing your own jvm. I'm sure that there are more special exceptions around.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those classes isn't really implemented with 'special' help from the compiler or JVM. Object does register some natives which poke around the internal JVM structures, but you can do that for your own classes as well. (I admit this is subject to semantics, "calls a native defined in the JVM" can be considered as special JVM support.)

What /is/ special is the behaviour of the 'new', and 'throw' instructions in how they initialise these internal structures.

Annotations and numbers are pretty much all-out freaky though.

Comment: aioobe refers to classes you can not implement yourself, as they have special build in support. You cannot create your own Object class as root of the type system without inheriting form java.lang.Object. Object has special support from both the compiler and the jvm to make sure it is a root class. Native calls are not enough to get around this.