# In one process, how can we create another process that is an exact copy of the parent?

Tags: java, process

Using java in one process, how can we create another process that is an exact copy of the parent?

Comment: Could you elaborate? What process do you mean, a system process?

Comment: What is the goal you want to reach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that using pure Java. In the C world you'd simply use [the `fork()` system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29), but Java has no direct support for this.

You *might* be able to call `fork()` from some [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) code (or using [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)), but I doubt that your average JVM implementation is built to handle that gracefully.

Comment: +1 Good answer. There is a discussion on creating threads in JNI [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478150/custom-implementation-of-thread-in-java-is-it-possible-though-jni).

Comment: @aioobe - the question, and @Joachim's answer are about creating processes not threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another process which has the same command line arguments with Runtime.exec(). However you cannot do a C-style fork from pure Java.  It would be heard to imagine why you would want to.

I suspect what you are trying to do is best done another way. Can you give more details as you why you want to do this?